# onBackPressed for two seperate pages from one page in Android

Tags: android, onbackpressed

I'm kind of new to Android. I'm implementing a small android application. It has 3 pages.

Page A

Page B

Page C

There are buttons in Page A and Page B which can go to Page C. What I need to know is, when I goto Page C by clicking on Page A button I need to go back to Page A using `onBackPressed()` and when I goto Page C by clicking on Page B button I need to go back to Page B using `onBackPressed()`

Here is the code I used.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
        startActivity(new Intent(C.this, A.class));
        finish();

    }
```

As far as I know I can't call two `onBackPressed()` in the same class.

So, what should I do?

- edit -

Start Activity C from A/B

```
 btnFromC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), C.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I am not sure the issue you are having. If you remove the onBackPressed() method, you should have that expected functionality. `A -> Button Pressed -> C -> Back pressed -> A`. That is standard functionality. If by `Page` you mean an `Activity`.

Comment: How do you start the C Intent from Page A or B because as @Knossos the normal behaviour is that it's added to the backStack.

Comment: Yeah Page means Activity What I need is A -> Button Pressed -> C -> Back pressed -> A and B -> Button Pressed -> C -> Back pressed -> B

Comment: from your activity a and b startactivty but don't finish. and in activity c's onBack press just put finish();

Comment: Also, make sure that you do not have `noHistory` set in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: just remove onBackPressed from all your activities, it should work fine

Comment: @cherry-vawe, by using Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), C.class);

Comment: @kishorepatel , If i remove onBackPressed, App just exists by clicking back button other than going to it's previous page. :)

Comment: Pls show your code to start activity C from A and B

Comment: Remove ``finish()`` function when start activity. And remove ``onBackPress`` in C class

Comment: didn't work @ Danh DC. Can't I use the specific class name and do this? :)

Comment: @NoNameeee hmm, in class A/B only have one button to go C or more ?

Comment: show your complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, is not the Best answer but it works:

Activity A:

```
btnFromC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), C.class);
                intent.putExtra("comeFrom", 0);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Activity B:

```
btnFromC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), C.class);
                intent.putExtra("comeFrom", 1);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Activity C:

```
 int comeFrom;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         Intent intent = this.getIntent();
         comeFrom = intent.getIntExtra("comeFrom", 0);
}

@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
  Intent intent = null;

       switch(comeFrom){
      case 0:
        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), A.class);
        break;
      case 1:
        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), B.class);
        break;
       }
       startActivity(intent);

    }
```

Solve your problem?

Comment: Wow. This is grt. Thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

From Activity A and B start c like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(A or B.this, c.class));
```

and in your class c

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    super.onBackPressed();        
    finish();

}
```